# How to keep a servo running only for a specified amount of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio, servo

Right now when I call my up function it will continuously spin the servo pulling up a winch and when I input down it will continuously lower the winch. I want to make the servo spin for X amount of seconds then it will stop.

Right now it will spin infinitely. How would I make it only spin for a specified amount of time?

```
def up_function ():

    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import signal
    from time import sleep
    
    
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
    pwm=GPIO.PWM(17,50)
    pwm.start(0)

    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(2)
    sleep(0)

    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(2)
    sleep(0)

    pwm.ChangeDutyCylce(0)

    pwm.stop()
    
    time.sleep(1)
    

def down_function ():
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    from time import sleep
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)

    pwm=GPIO.PWM(17,50)
    pwm.start(0)

    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(12.4)
    sleep(0)

    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(12.5)
    sleep(0)

    pwm.ChangeDutyCylce(0)

    pwm.stop()
    

up = input ("Please Input Up or Down: ")

if up == 'up':
    up_function ()
elif up == 'down':
    down_function ()
#elif keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
    #print("Exiting Program")
    #sys.exit(0)
else:
    print('Exiting Program')
```

Comment: One way would be to use a [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) and schedule a call to a function to turn it off after the specified amount of time. Another would be to use [`sched.scheduler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#module-sched) to do something similar.

Comment: As good practice, you should move all of the imports to the top of the file.